# can I use a 5400mAh battery in my Toshiba L40-17m laptop?

Tags: battery

I recently bought a replacement battery for my Toshiba Equium L40-17M laptop. It is showing a 5400 mAh. Usually it seems this model takes a 4400mAh. Will the larger mAh damage my laptop?

Comment: I shouldn't do.

Just because it is capable of a larger output doesn't mean it will give that if not requested.

Answer (score 1):

No, it won’t damage your laptop. It’s a measurement unit for a battery’s energy capacity. A battery with different capacity will never damage a device unless the more important specifications don’t match: **It’s all about voltage and current.**

In voltage, it has to be the same.

In current, the battery must be able to supply at least as much as the previous/original power source. Otherwise, the battery might get damaged and/or your system may crash because of insufficient power.

Comment: Note that it will take longer to charge the battery.  If it previously took around 4 hours, the new one will take around 5 hrs.